# Unable to Install : Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package

Tags: wix, installation

I am trying to install an application(.msi), I used WiX installer to create a exe(it has depenendcies). I tried installing it in some of the PC and it works perfectly fine. But in one of the system when it is trying to install the msi it givens an error and roll backs the installation(which is normal).

Unable to figure out why it is not installing in this specific machine. Any suggestions.?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Im getting an error "Failed to set security descriptor on object C:\, system errror: - 2147024891"

Comment: `-2147024891` = `0x80070005` = Access Denied. Are you trying to set permissions on C:\? Update your question with the error and any other relevant information (such as snippets from your wxs file).

Comment: I'm not setting any permission on C drive. I am installing it in that location which is keeping all the relevant data in it (things which happen in any installation).

Answer (score 8):

This article seems to indicate that it's a generic issue - the system needs a reboot:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/974061

so that's the first thing to try. If the issue persists it's probably something to do with the system being stuck in a state where it thinks there's a install still running. They could look at this to see the registry items that can affect this:

http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/error/1618.htm

If you install the MSI file producing a log then it may show what's going on: msiexec /I [path to msi file] /l*vx [path to text log file]

It's possible that there is something in your setup that is causing this on that machine, especially if it performs another setup or a driver install (or something like that) that leaves the system in a state where it needs a reboot to continue your installation. Also, sometimes it's useful to add the MsiSystemRebootPending property as a launch condition so you don't start the install if a reboot is pending:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370492(v=vs.85).aspx

The error (from the comment) -2147024891 is 0x80070005, Access is denied. There does seem to be an occasional error where the system account loses access to some folders, so that may be the issue in this particular case. If the access to the C:\ drive (and maybe some others) do not allow full access to the SYSTEM account then that could result in some odd downstream problems.

Comment: +1 for msi log command line. You will get 0x80070643 if you return Failure from a custom action. The log will at least give you the action run just prior to the error/what caused the error and you can continue from there.

Comment: Agreed, the KB article indicating a reboot is required is likely to be a red herring. 1603 errors are caused for many different reasons. If it's a custom action, searching the verbose log for "return value 3" can be very enlightening.

Comment: I have no custom actions to be executed. There are some prerequisites that I'm installing like .NET framework and then installing my MSI. Moreover when I just try to install the MSI without installing the dependencies then also its the same case. The error im getting is "Failed to set security descriptor on object C:\, system errror: - 2147024891"

Comment: Get that log and post it somewhere!

Comment: @PhilDW : I have shared the log in google drive,
[https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BztFifp9xUrLV0E4Z3QwRVVyS28

Comment: Abdulla: that's the WiX bundle log, not the MSI verbose log. If you can install the MSI separately please use the msiexec command line I posted.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d

It downloads a troubleshooter and it works! after troubleshooting, I can uninstall my program.

The error that caused mine is having this in my Products.wxs (WiX setup project):

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Before="InstallInitialize" Action="WixCloseApplications">REMOVE = "ALL"</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have suffered the same problem. For future users facing with similar issue.

- 0x80070005 Failed to create registration key
- Error 0x80070659: Failed to install MSI package, Failed to execute MSI package, Failed to configure per-machine MSI package, Error 0x80070659: Failed to execute MSI package
- Could not open key: UNKNOWN\Components\xx\yy.   Verify that you have sufficient access to that key, or contact your support personnel.

In my case, I use Process Monitor to check installation process.
Found error (`MainEngineThread is returning 1625`) occur just in RegQueryKey-SUCCESS-RegOpenKey-SUCCESS-RegQueryValue-**NAME NOT FOUND**-RegCloseKey.

After I disable the KEY (by delete or rename).
The installation could continue, creating new key-value, treated as `Product not registered: beginning first-time install`.

So, the reason seems to be there is some old un-cleaned registry detected(especially at `HKCR\Installer\Products`).

Also, could first try check log of `msiexec.exe`.
And it's not related with Group Policy Object (GPO) or special config on computer.

When searching for my issue, I google here, thanks for sharing.
And I post my summarize at [SOLIDWORKS VC VSTA 安装 权限 注册表 策略组 相关问题 (Most in Chinese, but have a lot reference)](https://www.cnblogs.com/RobertL/p/14275499.html).