# could not access network location while installing Microsoft .NET Runtime - 6.0.1 (x64)

Tags: .net, windows

Before everything, im sorry if this is not the place for asking this type of question i saw a lot of people with knowledge and thought that maybe i could get the help i need.

Now to the problem i have, when i try to install Microsoft .Net 5.0.13 or 6.0.1(this are the ones i tried) i get the error message "could not access network location" i dont know why this happens, tried some solutions like "Regedit" and updating my computer to the last update but it didnt work, the program showed me a log with the process it took and where it stopped here it is:

````
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:17]i000: Initializing string variable 'BUNDLEMONIKER' to value 'Microsoft .NET Runtime - 6.0.1 (x64)'
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:17]i000: Initializing string variable 'PRODUCT_NAME' to value 'Microsoft .NET Runtime - 6.0.1 (x64)'
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:17]i000: Initializing string variable 'LINK_PREREQ_PAGE' to value 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=846817'
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:17]i009: Command Line: '-burn.clean.room=E:\download\dotnet-runtime-6.0.1-win-x64.exe -burn.filehandle.attached=596 -burn.filehandle.self=576'
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:17]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'E:\download\dotnet-runtime-6.0.1-win-x64.exe'
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:17]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'E:\download\'
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:17]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Windows\TEMP\Microsoft_.NET_Runtime_-_6.0.1_(x64)_20220113135817.log'
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:17]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Microsoft .NET Runtime - 6.0.1 (x64)'
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:17]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Microsoft Corporation'
[24E0:24F4][2022-01-13T13:58:17]i000: Setting numeric variable 'WixStdBALanguageId' to value 1033
[24E0:24F4][2022-01-13T13:58:17]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '6.0.1.30717'
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:18]i100: Detect begin, 3 packages
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:18]i101: Detected package: dotnet_runtime_6.0.1_win_x64.msi, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:18]i101: Detected package: dotnet_hostfxr_6.0.1_win_x64.msi, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:18]i101: Detected package: dotnet_host_6.0.1_win_x64.msi, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:18]i052: Condition '((VersionNT > v6.1) OR (VersionNT = v6.1 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1))' evaluates to true.
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:18]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:18]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:19]i200: Plan begin, 3 packages, action: Install
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:19]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_dotnet_runtime_6.0.1_win_x64.msi' to value 'C:\Windows\TEMP\Microsoft_.NET_Runtime_-_6.0.1_(x64)_20220113135817_000_dotnet_runtime_6.0.1_win_x64.msi_rollback.log'
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:19]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_dotnet_runtime_6.0.1_win_x64.msi' to value 'C:\Windows\TEMP\Microsoft_.NET_Runtime_-_6.0.1_(x64)_20220113135817_000_dotnet_runtime_6.0.1_win_x64.msi.log'
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:19]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_dotnet_hostfxr_6.0.1_win_x64.msi' to value 'C:\Windows\TEMP\Microsoft_.NET_Runtime_-_6.0.1_(x64)_20220113135817_001_dotnet_hostfxr_6.0.1_win_x64.msi_rollback.log'
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:19]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_dotnet_hostfxr_6.0.1_win_x64.msi' to value 'C:\Windows\TEMP\Microsoft_.NET_Runtime_-_6.0.1_(x64)_20220113135817_001_dotnet_hostfxr_6.0.1_win_x64.msi.log'
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:19]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_dotnet_host_6.0.1_win_x64.msi' to value 'C:\Windows\TEMP\Microsoft_.NET_Runtime_-_6.0.1_(x64)_20220113135817_002_dotnet_host_6.0.1_win_x64.msi_rollback.log'
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:19]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_dotnet_host_6.0.1_win_x64.msi' to value 'C:\Windows\TEMP\Microsoft_.NET_Runtime_-_6.0.1_(x64)_20220113135817_002_dotnet_host_6.0.1_win_x64.msi.log'
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:19]i201: Planned package: dotnet_runtime_6.0.1_win_x64.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:19]i201: Planned package: dotnet_hostfxr_6.0.1_win_x64.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:19]i201: Planned package: dotnet_host_6.0.1_win_x64.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:19]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:19]i300: Apply begin
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:19]i010: Launching elevated engine process.
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:29]i011: Launched elevated engine process.
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:29]i012: Connected to elevated engine.
[2AF4:2AF0][2022-01-13T13:58:29]i358: Pausing automatic updates.
[2AF4:2AF0][2022-01-13T13:58:30]i359: Paused automatic updates.
[2AF4:2AF0][2022-01-13T13:58:30]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{6a233b20-b79f-4570-a6a0-cf6c1a3a39d0}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[2AF4:2AF0][2022-01-13T13:58:30]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Windows\TEMP\{4A054453-AC6D-48C6-BE1F-82EB1818DF7C}\.be\dotnet-runtime-6.0.1-win-x64.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{6a233b20-b79f-4570-a6a0-cf6c1a3a39d0}\dotnet-runtime-6.0.1-win-x64.exe'
[2AF4:2AF0][2022-01-13T13:58:30]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {6a233b20-b79f-4570-a6a0-cf6c1a3a39d0}, version: 6.0.1.30717
[2AF4:2AF0][2022-01-13T13:58:30]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{6a233b20-b79f-4570-a6a0-cf6c1a3a39d0}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[2AF4:14B8][2022-01-13T13:58:30]i304: Verified existing payload: dotnet_runtime_6.0.1_win_x64.msi at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{97CC09C6-5CD8-4C2B-B4C2-235BBFC713DB}v48.7.32725\dotnet-runtime-6.0.1-win-x64.msi.
[2AF4:2AF0][2022-01-13T13:58:30]i301: Applying execute package: dotnet_runtime_6.0.1_win_x64.msi, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{97CC09C6-5CD8-4C2B-B4C2-235BBFC713DB}v48.7.32725\dotnet-runtime-6.0.1-win-x64.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1"'
[2AF4:14B8][2022-01-13T13:58:30]i304: Verified existing payload: dotnet_hostfxr_6.0.1_win_x64.msi at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{50008A1B-8D93-4292-ABBB-B439EBC9F425}v48.7.32725\dotnet-hostfxr-6.0.1-win-x64.msi.
[2AF4:14B8][2022-01-13T13:58:30]i304: Verified existing payload: dotnet_host_6.0.1_win_x64.msi at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{4E77768C-3EF9-428C-BE54-EB82BB9426AB}v48.7.32725\dotnet-host-6.0.1-win-x64.msi.
[2AF4:2AF0][2022-01-13T13:58:38]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
[2AF4:2AF0][2022-01-13T13:58:38]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:38]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:38]w348: Application requested retry of package: dotnet_runtime_6.0.1_win_x64.msi, encountered error: 0x80070643. Retrying...
[2AF4:2AF0][2022-01-13T13:58:41]i301: Applying execute package: dotnet_runtime_6.0.1_win_x64.msi, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{97CC09C6-5CD8-4C2B-B4C2-235BBFC713DB}v48.7.32725\dotnet-runtime-6.0.1-win-x64.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1"'
[2AF4:2AF0][2022-01-13T13:58:42]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed to install MSI package.
[2AF4:2AF0][2022-01-13T13:58:42]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed to execute MSI package.
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:42]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:42]i319: Applied execute package: dotnet_runtime_6.0.1_win_x64.msi, result: 0x80070642, restart: None
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:42]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed to execute MSI package.
[2AF4:2AF0][2022-01-13T13:58:42]i318: Skipped rollback of package: dotnet_runtime_6.0.1_win_x64.msi, action: Uninstall, already: Absent
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:42]i319: Applied rollback package: dotnet_runtime_6.0.1_win_x64.msi, result: 0x0, restart: None
[2AF4:2AF0][2022-01-13T13:58:42]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{6a233b20-b79f-4570-a6a0-cf6c1a3a39d0}, resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No
[2AF4:2AF0][2022-01-13T13:58:42]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {6a233b20-b79f-4570-a6a0-cf6c1a3a39d0}
[2AF4:2AF0][2022-01-13T13:58:42]i352: Removing cached bundle: {6a233b20-b79f-4570-a6a0-cf6c1a3a39d0}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{6a233b20-b79f-4570-a6a0-cf6c1a3a39d0}\
[2AF4:2AF0][2022-01-13T13:58:42]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{6a233b20-b79f-4570-a6a0-cf6c1a3a39d0}, resume: None, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[24E0:24D0][2022-01-13T13:58:42]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070642, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No```

I apreciate any help, Thanks!.
````

Comment: Perhaps this will help: [unable-to-install-error-0x80070643-failed-to-install-msi-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720158/unable-to-install-error-0x80070643-failed-to-install-msi-package)

Comment: Thanks, i will try it out.

Comment: @RyanWilson it didnt work,unfortunately, it seems like a reboot is the best guess at this point still, thanks for the help.

Comment: Messing around with the registry can be dangerous. Perhaps try running the FixIt tool on your machine.

Comment: @RyanWilson Is the FixIt tool the troubleshoot? if thats the case i alredy tried with the apps in my pc (but it didnt find .Net so i couldnt try to fix that install or app in specific) and the update (sayed that it fixed some problem in the computer but the install couldnt proceed still) i did this after i saw your comment searching solutions.